# What mistake i have in condition with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, conditional-statements

I'm working on a little browser game, but when I have a condition in connection to **MySQLi database**, it doesn't work.

In **else** closure it should write $name, but it doesn't.

```
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

else{
    //IF CONNECTION IS GOOD, GET DATA FROM DATABASE
    $query = "SELECT name, separator, description, maintenance FROM configuration";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $name = $row['name'];
    //this ↓↓↓
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: `seperator` is a MySQL reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back ticks (``) when using reserved words.

From,

```
$query = "SELECT name, separator, description, maintenance FROM configuration";
```

To,

```
$query = "SELECT name, `separator`, description, maintenance FROM configuration";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with backticks:

```
$query = "SELECT name, `separator`, description, maintenance FROM configuration";
```